# Convert a set<String> datatype to String Data type in android

Tags: android, string, types

I am using a amazon apps with my android apps.

`PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuKye);` is defined the error like skuKye is string.U have to convert it into the set  data type.

Please guide me

Comment: The method initiateItemDataRequest(Set<String>) in the type PurchasingManager is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: String skuKye="DeveloperSKU-1234";

Comment: PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuKye); the error is occur in this place.

Answer (score 3):

The `initiateItemDataRequest` method requires a `Set<String>` containing the SKUs for the request. If you have only one SKU, you should be able to call it this way:

```
Set<String> skuSet = new HashSet<String>();
skuSet.add(skuKye);
PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuSet);
```

Comment: skus is comes from where?? i am using this way  String skuKye="DeveloperSKU-1234";
 final Set<String> skuSet = new HashSet<String>();
 skuSet.add(skuKye);
 but is display the same error like Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "skuKye", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: @user1838195 - sorry, that was a typo (now fixed). It was supposed to be `skuSet`. The code in your comment looks okay to me. Which line exactly has the syntax error? Did you import `Set` and `HashSet` from `java.util`? (Perhaps you can edit your question and post the exact code, formatted for readability. Also post a few lines around it, in case a nearby syntax error is causing the message.)

Comment: @user1838195 - Also, what are some of the other error markers on that line?